# Italy tourist visa refusal

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, italy

I traveled to Italy two times previously 10 years ago and applied for a tourist visa last year (2017). Unfortunately, my visa was rejected and objection raised on me that

> **Justification of attended stay and condition is not provided**

All of my attached documents are perfect except that in my previous visits I didn't enter and leave Italy directly; rather I entered once from France and second from Amsterdam. I have paper evidence that I was in Italy previously.

I like to re-apply again this year kindly guide me.

Comment: @AliAwan There is a big difference between "not provided" and "not reliable". This is why we have separate Q&As for them.

Comment: @Michael Hampton ok